# Deleting a value only from a key on HashMap

Tags: java

I have set up a HashMap which populates with customers details as values (name, postcode, item) and the keys being say Customer1, Customer2 etc.

I want a method to delete just value "item" from each key, my code at the moment is as per below but when i run it the "item" value from argument isn't deleted.

```
public void deleteThisValue(String value)
{
    if (this.customer.containsValue(value))
    {
        this.customer.remove(value);
    }
}
```

Now in my head this works but it obviously doesn't, can anyone shed any light on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: iterate over the values...

Comment: You said _from a key_ so the parameter `value` is a `key` ? So you should check if `this.customer.containsKey(value)` instead. Please be more specific

Comment: How are you declaring `this.customer`?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about how you have declared Customer1, Customer2, provide your code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate over the values...then invoking the get method of the map will return the reference of the value, on that reference you can invoke a setter.

```
myMap.get(x).setItem("newItem");
        //or 
myMap.get(x).setItem(-1);
```

it depends what is Item for a type....

example:

```
    Map<String, Pojo> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("A", new Customer2());
    myMap.put("B", new Customer2());
    myMap.put("C", new Customer2());

    for (String x : myMap.keySet()) {
        myMap.get(x).setItem("newItem");
        //or 
        myMap.get(x).setItem(-1);
    }
    System.out.println(myMap);
```

## Edit:

since java8 is offering streams, you can use those nice features doing:

```
myMap.values().stream().forEach(x -> x.setItem("none"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove` method works with key only,

If you want to remove value only, then you can set value as `null` for that key.
e.g:

```
this.customer.put(key,null);
```

But if you want to set a particular value (say item) of value then you can do this something like that:

```
this.customer.get(key).setItem(null);
```

Comment: I get that, but i want to keep the other values against the key?

Comment: @Bob What other value ? There is only 1 value per key in a map. That's the point.

Comment: @AxelH Customer 1 has three values such as name, postcode, item, ideally, OP would like to delete only item, name and postcode should remain in the list.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i meant element of value, say my customer1 has value of customersContents with elements (name, postcode, item). I want to delete item from that list of elements..

Comment: @user75ponic But if I get it, `map.put("Cust1", name); map.put("Cust1", item);`, the name will be override by the item. Unless he used a `Map<Customer>` but nothing show that in the question.

Comment: @AxelH Yes unless OP is using Map, it would be impossible to have one key and multiple values.